# Visualization of a system of two electron orbitals

Tags: electrons, schroedinger-equation, orbitals

There are many clear and beautiful 3D pictures of different orbitals of a single electron: sphere-symmetric s orbitals, p-, d- and so on.

But what is about systems of many electron? In this case there are many orbitals as a probability distributions and they should intersect with each other like on a picture below.

[image]

As I understand, the single-electron approximation is widely used today for such cases. And I feel uncomfortable with it.
Is there any approaches to visualization of, say, *real* two electron orbitals? Of course, here we have probability distributions living in 6D space. So, may be there is some possibility to plot distribution for one electron when the second one conditionally placed in some fixed point? Or may be something else.

Has anyone tried to solve Schrodinger equation for two electrons numerically and plot some pretty plots of probability joint/conditional distributions?

Comment: *But what is about systems of many electron?* Remember Pauli? Each MO cannot contain more than $2$ electrons.

Comment: OK, let it be only two :). What's about Helium? Has anyone plot Helium electron's joint/conditional probability distribution?

Comment: I doubt if it's worth doing: a $1s^2$ orbital will look very much like a $1s^1$ orbital.